# Deleteing unused leased VHDs not attached to any Disk

Tags: azure

After cleaning my Azure infrastructure there some remaining VHDs listed as Leased but which I'm sure they are not referenced by any VM / Disk.

I have mapped every listed VM with every Disk listed under Disks with every VHD listed in the Storage account Blobs, I expected to get the same number of Disks as VHDs but there are many more of the last. They are not used by any VM and they last modification time is clearly very old, but I have no way to delete them via the portal nor can I track why are they marked as leased.

How can I safely delete this VHDs?

**Note:** All these VHDs have been created using Classic deployment method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These VHDs are lying around probably when the VMs they were associated with were deleted, whosoever deleted them chose not to delete the VHDs along with the VM. These VHDs are leased with infinite lease so that they are not deleted accidentally (or intentionally) while a VM is still tied to those.

If you're sure that there are no VMs associated with these VHDs, you can safely delete them. However because these VHDs are leased, you can't delete them directly. First you will have to break the lease.

You can use Microsoft's Storage Explorer (or any other Azure Storage Explorer that supports lease breaking) to break the lease. Simply connect to the storage account in question, and explore the blobs in the blob container containing these VHDs. Then select the blob and choose "Break Lease" option from the context menu.

Once the lease is broken, you can then delete these VHDs.

Comment: Thanks, finally I could do it from Azure Portal. The VHDs list in the Storage Account panel had an option to break the lease and then delete a VHD, so I need not to download the Storage Explorer.